# Change field value when button is clicked with AlpineJS

Tags: alpine.js

Is there a way to change the a field value when a button is clicked with AlpineJS?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="flex flex-col items-center" x-data="{on:false}">
    <div class="flex items-center w-full">
        <button type="button" class="bg-gray-200 relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500" aria-pressed="false" :aria-pressed="on.toString()" @click="on = !on" x-state:on="Enabled" x-state:off="Not Enabled" :class="{ 'bg-blue-600': on, 'bg-gray-200': !(on) }">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="translate-x-0 pointer-events-none inline-block h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform ring-0 transition ease-in-out duration-200" x-state:on="Enabled" x-state:off="Not Enabled" :class="{ 'translate-x-5': on, 'translate-x-0': !(on) }"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="text-sm ml-3">Enable Button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex w-full bg-gray-50 p-4 mt-4 rounded-lg" x-show="on" x-transition:enter-start="transition ease-in duration-3000">
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center w-full" x-data="{on:false}">
            <input type="text" name="filesRequired" id="filesRequired">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basicly, what I am trying is to add the value "1" to `<input type="text" name="filesRequired" id="filesRequired">` field when the button is enabled (`{on:true}`) and remove the value if `{on:false}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the following work? It uses `x-bind:` to set `value="1"` when `on` is true and removes `value` when `on` is false.

`<input type="text" name="filesRequired" id="filesRequired" x-bind:value="on ? 1 : undefined">`